# how to load .rpt file from specific folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I am using access database ,and VS2010,I am trying to load crystal report but getting this error for this line ,what is wrong with `server` how should i write this

`rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("C:/Users/Monika/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/SonoRepo/SonoRepo/Report/PatientCrystalReport.rpt"));`
 for `server`

**Code**

```
private void ViewReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
            PatientDataset ds = new PatientDataset(); // .xsd file name
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            // Just set the name of data table
            dt.TableName = "Patient Crystal Report ";
            dt = getAllPatients(); //This function is located below this function
            ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);


           //getting error here
           // Your .rpt file path will be below

            rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("C:/Users/Monika/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/SonoRepo/SonoRepo/Report/PatientCrystalReport.rpt"));

            //set dataset to the report viewer.
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
            PatientCrystalReport.ReportSource = rptDoc;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without `Server.MapPath`:

```
rptDoc.Load(@"C:\....rpt");
```

`MapPath` is intended for use by server-side code in web programming. Since you're using WinForms, it's useless.

Comment: what if the File present in the same Solution?

Comment: Can you Please suggest me ?